# AttributeError: 'PDFPage' object has no attribute 'extractText'

Tags: python, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract the content from a PDF in order to create an excel sheet out of it.

### What I tried

```
import pdfquery 
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('C:\\Users\\Santosh\\Downloads\\2017-San-Jamar-
Price-List-US-Z120913E-RevA.pdf')
page = pdf.get_page(3)
page_content = page.extractText()
print (page_content)
```

It throws the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-d6b615faa422> in <module>() 
      1 page = pdf.get_page(3)
----> 2 page_content = page.extractText()
      3 print (page_content)

AttributeError: 'PDFPage' object has no attribute 'extractText'
```

Please let me know a possible solution.

Comment: where is your source saying that a PDF page object **should** have a method called `extractText`?

Comment: Sorry I could not reply. This one is resolved.

Comment: 2023 update: [`PyPDF2` is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/). **Use `pypdf`**. I'm the maintainer of both libraries

Answer (score 2):

Use [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) instead of pdfquery

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader('C:\\Users\\Santosh\\Downloads\\2017-San-Jamar-
Price-List-US-Z120913E-RevA.pdf')
page = reader.pages[3]
print(page.extract_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had also face the same issue. This is due to the non updated version of pypdf2 package installed already with other pdf reader dependencies. By reinstalling pypdf2 is resolved my error.

```
pip uninstall pypdf2
pip install pypdf2
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled PyPDF2 after uninstalling PyPDF and PyPDF, and the issue was resolved.

```
pip uninstall PyPDF
pip uninstall PyPDF2
pip install PyPDF2
```